# Azure pipeline uses expression and not value

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I use the following azure pipeline (it is simplified for testing):

```
parameters:
  - name: BUILD_QUALITY
    displayName: What is the build quality?
    type: string
    default: "alpha"
    values:
      - alpha
      - beta
      - preview
      - release

trigger: none

variables:
  solution: "**/*.sln"
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: "Release"
  patch: $[counter(variables['CustomVersion'], 1)]
  versionNumber: $(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)
  ${{ if eq( parameters['BUILD_QUALITY'], 'release') }}:
    VERSION_NUMBER: ${{ variables.versionNumber }}.$(patch)
  ${{ else }}:
    VERSION_NUMBER: ${{ variables.versionNumber }}.$(patch)-${{parameters['BUILD_QUALITY']}}

name: Test_${{ variables.versionNumber }}.$(patch)

pool:
  vmImage: "windows-latest"

stages:
  - stage: buildCliTool

    jobs:
      - job: cliTool
        steps:
          - script: echo "versionNumber is ${{ variables.versionNumber }}"
          - script: echo "Build name is $(Build.BuildNumber)"

          
  - stage: buildNuget

    jobs:
      - job: nuget
        steps:
          - script: echo "versionNumber is $(versionNumber)"
          - script: echo "versionNumber is $(VERSION_NUMBER)"
```

Script steps are used to check, whether variables values are correct.
But, they print correct value just for expression `- script: echo "Build name is $(Build.BuildNumber)"`

[image]

In all other cases, output is not value, but expression itself.

[image]

I'd like to use `versionNumber` in my stages, but now it does not have proper value.
Could someone suggest please, how should I use that variable to obtain value, and not expression body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the tokens you're using in this variable:

```
versionNumber: $(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)
```

Those *year*, *month* and *dayofmonth* tokens – you can't use them in normal variables, only when [defining a build number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#tokens):

> You can use these tokens only to define a run number; they don't work anywhere else in your pipeline.